# Where to specify Apache2 Virtual Hosts in CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm used to Ubuntu, where there is a special file for containing the virtual hosts.
But I'm getting the impression that in CentOS the virtual hosts are listed right in the main configuration file.

Can anyone confirm this?

EDIT - Tried this and it didn't work:

Added this to httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       ErrorLog /var/www/example_apache_errors.log
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
       <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               allow from all
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It did not work. The test page I created at /var/www/html/example/index.html is not showing up. Instead, the default page at /var/www/html/index.html is showing up.

EDIT: before anyone asks, yes, I'm restarting apache after ever config change.

EDIT:

**NameVirtualHost *:80** is commented out by default in the config file and I didn't uncomment it. I believe that was the problem.

But I decided to use ip-based instead, like this:

```
<VirtualHost 69.175.xxx.xxx:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/

# etc. etc.

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is working. We have 5 ip's so hopefully I can use this method to assign others in the future.

Comment: You have "NameVirtualHost *:80" turned on?  And "sudo apachectl configtest" is returning OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that you can just stick something like:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
```

into /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, run "mkdir -p /etc/httpd/sites-enabled /etc/httpd/sites-available" and get something similar to the Ubuntu directory structure for Apache, right?

Update (from information in comments):

You should verify that NameVirtualHosts for port 80 is turned on, also.

Comment: Yes, I know that now that you've told me and I will certainly try that if nothing else works. But what is standard practice on CentOS? I would rather not be too creative on the server config. I just want to do things the way they're usually done on CentOS if possible.

Comment: On my CentOS 5 box, I did an include of a virthosts.conf file which contained all my virtual hosts.  On my CentOS 6, I'm following Ubuntu conventions, after a couple years exposure to how Ubuntu does things.  I think as long as you document your changes and aren't insane about directory layout, it should be OK. I think it's much worse putting everything in the main httpd.conf file, for whatever my opinion matters.

Comment: A separate file does seem more elegant. I will try that, but since I can't even get it to work inside the file I'm wondering if something else is wrong.

Comment: NameVirtualHost was commented out in the config file, so I think your comment was right on.  Although, I did not test it because I ended up using ip-based VirtualHost instead. Your answer is good but I think you should add something about NameVirtualHost *:80 to it so I can give you the check mark. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, check mark for you and gave you a +1. Thanks also for your answer on my other question although not sure if I want to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

Since Centos has the `Include conf.d/*.conf` I place my configs there. However I typically have a `conf.d/00_NameVirtualHost.conf` with `NameVirtualHost *:80`. Im guessing you don't have that set in your apache config.